# Mule; How can I make sure the flow completes without it being triggered again by the Quartz scheduer

Tags: mule, quartz-scheduler

I have a requirement in which the start of the flow is triggered to load customer data from a SQL database into a Mongo DB database. All the current trades need to be moved to the Mongo DB. Once the migration of current trades to MongoDB is complete, it is intended that new trades would start to be monitored and copied to MongoDB. The goal is to trigger the flow that monitors new customer trades to start after all the current customer trades has been moved to MongoDB. The problem is that moving the current customer trades is to be triggered from a property in a properties file.

```
   <flow name="migrateCurrentTrades">
     <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Task" 
       cronExpression="0 */2 * * * ?" jobName="mailJob" 
      repeatInterval="1000000" 
                                         repeatCount="0">
            <quartz:event-generator-job/>
       </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
     <flow-ref name="readAndSave">
     <!-- This actually is a reference to a groovy script that starts the
             monitorCustomerActivity  flow below in the 'stopped'
            initialState
          -->

      <script-ref name="startMonitorCustomerActivityFlow"/>
   </flow>


     <!-- long running job----->
   <sub-flow name="readAndSave">
      <db:select  config-ref="mySQLConfig">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[
             SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER c WHERE status='ACTIVE'   
            ]]>
      </db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
       <custom-transformer  class="com.gdc.CustomerTransformer" />
      <!-- Save to Mongo DB -- via queue -->
      <vm:outbound-endpoint path="mongodb-queue" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
   </sub-flow>



  <flow name="monitorCustomerActivity" initialState="stopped">
     <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Task" 
       cronExpression="0 */45 * * * ?" jobName="mailJob" repeatInterval="0" 
                                         repeatCount="0">
            <quartz:event-generator-job/>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
       <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[
             SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_TRADES c WHERE trade_status='NEW' 
            ]]>
  </db:parameterized-query>
  </db:select>

    <custom-transformer class="com.gdc.TradesTransformer" />

   <!-- Save to Mongo DB -- via queue -->
      <vm:outbound-endpoint path="mongodb-queue" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
   </flow>
```

Unfortunately, the readAndSave flow keeps running repeatedly because it takes too long to complete. I have set the repeatInterval to a very high value and repeatCount to 0.  I want the readAndSave flow to only be triggered once and for it to complete. Although it starts the second flow, monitorCustomerActivity, it starts to interleave with it causing errors. How can I solve this problem, making sure the readAndSave flow be called only once and  complete saving the current customer trades before calling the second flow monitorCustomerActivity? I have battled with the problem for days

Comment: Your configuration has some issues: you specified both `cronExpression` and `repeatInterval` + `repeatCount` which seems mutually exclusive as per the doc: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/quartz-connector. Maybe your flow is running repeatedly not because of slowness, but because the cron expression specifying to run every 2 min is used by Mule, ignoring repeat interval and count ;)

Comment: I removed the cron expression but mule still requires the repeatInterval. Doesn't setting the repeatInterval cause to run multiple times?

Comment: I set the repeatInterval to a very high number but that's really a hack. There doesn't seem to be a way to get the quartz scheduler to run just once.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below steps, Increased timeout, repeatCount = 0 + startdelay ( on  stop and start your anypoint/server it will wait for 20 secs and then the schedule starts).

Since it is Async, you can use flow instead of sub-flow.

```
 <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="60000" doc:name="Task" 
    jobName="mailJob" repeatInterval="1000000"  repeatCount="0" startDelay="20000"> <quartz:event-generator-job/>
   </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
```

etc ....

```
      make readAndsave subflow to  `flow`

    <flow name="readAndSave">
  <db:select  config-ref="mySQLConfig" doc:name="Database">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[
         SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER c WHERE status='ACTIVE'   
        ]]>
  </db:parameterized-query>
</db:select>
<logger message="readAndSave:Check how many times flow gets trigger by looking at this log entry" />
etc...
```